# Wireless gives error deauthenticating : (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I ran the [wireless debug script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108) but I am not very Linux savvy to understand the [output](https://pastebin.com/Zfe69hPd). Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

I am using Linux Mint 17.

The `lspci` command:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2114]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
```

The kernel version :

```
Linux 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

the `dmesg`:

```
[ 1086.669496] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'WLAN-E6D626' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```